# How To Use Custom Config File On Yii

Tags: php, yii, config

I'm using [Yii Framework](http://yiiframework.com) and I have custom **customconfig.php** file in config folder
I want using my **customconfig** :

```
<?php return array('var' => 'variable'); ?>
```

how i can I **get** my custom variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of passing variables to config is possible with `params` index of  array stored in main.php config file.

Lets assume that you have two config files: main.php and customconfig.php. In main.php you have base configuration, for example components, modules etc. It is standard config file used in Yii. Second file, customconfig.php is your custom file with your custom variables.

First of all, you need to create your customconfig.php file that returns array with `params` index:

```
<?php
//this is customconfig.php config file

return array(
    'params'=>array('variableName'=>'variableValue'),
);
```

Next step is merge your customconfig.php file content with array that contains config from main.php file:

```
<?php
//this is main.php config file

return CMap::mergeArray(
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/customconfig.php'), //here is path to custom config file
    array(

        //your config data

        'params'=>array(
            // ...
        ),
    )
);
```

Now you have access to variables from customconfig.php with `Yii::app()->params['variableName']`.

Comment: so i must using 'params'? can i change it? like 'myparams'?

Comment: Yes, you must using `params`, because it is property of `CModule` - base class of `CWebApplication`. So Yii have methods for getting only `params`, not user-custom data. But of course you can create in your custom config file array in `params` which key is `myparams` and get this like `Yii::app()->params['myparams']['variableName']`.